# Finite Interpretations of Logical Independence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, multisets

**Is the sentence $a$ independent of the set $A$?**

$a=\{$All philosophers are either obscure or shallow$\}$

$A=\{$All philosophers are either rationalists or empiricists; some rationalists are obscure; some empiricists are shallow$\}$

$A=\{
\forall x\, [Px \rightarrow (Rx \vee Ex)]$;
$\exists x\, [Rx\ \&\ Ox]$;
$\exists x\, [Ex\ \&\ Sx] \}$

$a=\{$
$\forall$x $[$Px $\rightarrow$ (Ox $\vee$ Sx)$]$ $\}$

Comment: Looks OK, except that for $A \models \neg a$ to be refuted, you want an interpretation in which all formulae in $A$ and $a$ are true.  (You say "$A \cup \neg a$ must be of the form $T \cup T$," but then do the right thing and show a structure in which $a$ is true.)

Comment: Thanks @Fabio for your help!

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: Your comment should be an answer. =) Also, Andy, it's better to spell out what you mean by "premise" and "conclusion".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $A \cup a$ must be of the form $T \cup F$
>
> Domain=$\{$1,2,3$\}$: P=$\{$1,3$\}$; R=$\{$1,3$\}$; E=$\{$1$\}$;
>   O=$\{$1,2$\}$; S=$\{$1,2$\}$.
>
> $\forall$x $[$Px $\rightarrow$ (Rx $\vee$ Ex)$]$ $\Rightarrow$ True as
>   all values in P are either in R or E.
>
> $\exists$x $[$Rx & Ox$]$ $\Rightarrow$ True as some values in R and
>   also in O.
>
> $\exists$x $[$Ex & Sx$]$ $\Rightarrow$ True as some values in E are
>   also in S.
>
> $\forall$x $[$Px $\rightarrow$ (Ox $\vee$ Sx)$]$ $\Rightarrow$ False
>   as 3 is not in O or S.

With true premise and a false conclusion, the inference of $A$ to $a$
is invalid.

> $A \cup \neg a$ must be of the form $T \cup T$
>
> Domain=$\{$1$\}$:
>   P=$\{$1$\}$; R=$\{$1$\}$; E=$\{$1$\}$; O=$\{$1$\}$; S=$\{$1$\}$.
>
> $\forall$x $[$Px $\rightarrow$ (Rx $\vee$ Ex)$]$ $\Rightarrow$ True as
>   all values in P are either in R or E.
>
> $\exists$x $[$Rx & Ox$]$ $\Rightarrow$ True as some values in R and
>   also in O.
>
> $\exists$x $[$Ex & Sx$]$ $\Rightarrow$ True as some values in E are
>   also in S.
>
> $\forall$x $[$Px $\rightarrow$ (Ox $\vee$ Sx)$]$ $\Rightarrow$ True as
>   all values of P are in either O or S.

With true premise and a true conclusion, negating $a$, the inference
of $A$ to $\neg a$ is invalid.

Since $A \cup a$ and $A \cup \neg a$ are both invalid, the the sentence $a$ is thus independent from the set $A$.